# xna coordinates set to model coordinates

Tags: 3d, xna, coordinates

Can anyone please point me in the direction of how to set coordinates in XNA to model coordinates. That is to say I have a 3D object in 3D space. From this object I have drawn 3 lines (up, forward and right).

But what I want to do is when I move the model, the lines have to move with the model, but always be pointing straight up, down left and right as if the model is still at 0,0,0 world coordinates.

I can move the model but when I do, the lines still point to 0,0,0 world coordinates. So now they are pointing straight up anymore, but at an angle to 0,0,0.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you can write some code samples it will be better.
Anyway, I think your 3 lines don't reference to the model `World` `Matrix`, that's why when you move your model the lines point to the origin, because their `World` still the same.